# Carry address over with customer's order when creating user

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, addresses

When a user is created with the same email as a customer, the orders are attached to that user account. I have a Customer Info custom field attached to the Users, and that is updated to include the order, which is great.

Is it possible for the addresses within that order to be carried over to that same Customer Info field as well? I know that if a new address is added now they're a user then that would be saved. But what about carrying over addresses from the pre-existing order?

Answer (score 1):

It's not implemented, but possible.  I think it should be part of Commerce core really, and done when the user is created by default.

In the meantime, my Register On Checkout plugin does this - https://github.com/bossanova808/CommerceRegisterOnCheckout

You could adapt this more generally I guess to listen to all user registrations and see if there are addresses to move over.

The actual code that updates the addresses is here: https://github.com/bossanova808/CommerceRegisterOnCheckout/blob/master/commerceregisteroncheckout/CommerceRegisterOnCheckoutPlugin.php#L312 ... but most of the init method would be relevant I guess.

Comment: I agree. Should be default behaviour. Your plugin directly addresses this and looks ideal. I will use it but could do with knowing whether the functionality will be added to Core soon? Luke?